# Retaining session variables on page redirect

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a JSP page from which I'm calling another JSP page using response.sendRedirect(recordUrl2). I have some session variables from the first JSP page which get lost after the redirect. Is there anything that can be done in the web.xml configuration xml file to preserve the session variables?

I added the following in the xml, but the variables weren't maintained:

```
<session-descriptor>
 <persistent-store-type>memory</persistent-store-type>
 <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>      
</session-descriptor>
```

I also tried response.encodeRedirectURL(recordUrl2) instead, but sessions variables weren't maintained.

Comment: Session variables should persist across page redirects, unless you clear the session somewhere or your redirect changes the host or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance redirecting to a JSP hosted in a different JavaEE container or within a different WAR/deployment than the one doing the redirect? That's the only reason, short of you having code somewhere that clears the session, that the second JSP would not be able to access the session.

Comment: The target JSP is hosted in the same container. A similar issue has been reported at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857239/jsp-redirect-session-loss-issues. Their suggestion of using encodeRedirectURL didn't work in my case.